# Is it possible to make an imaging array differential?

Tags: photoelectric-effect, imaging, sensor

As described in [this comment on a Slashdot post](https://science.slashdot.org/comments.pl?sid=10895347&cid=54858571), exposing an imaging sensor to light accumulates charge in a well (i.e. pixel) on a piece of silicon. The well can only hold so much charge (release so many electrons), though, so the detector will saturate if exposed to too many photons. My question is: is it physically possible to set up the detector such that a photon hitting one pixel charges up the well by one electron and a photon hitting its neighbor discharges (or charges in the other direction) by one electron? And I don't mean doing it with processing after readout - ideally this is something that would be totally passive. What I'm imaging, admittedly, is something like a pair of the classic bench-top [photoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoelectric_effect) experiments with their anodes and cathodes cross connected, but whether something like this can be realized in a silicon imaging array of some sort that can be read out is the question.

Such differential imaging, if possible, would greatly increase the dynamic range of sensors.

Comment: May be physically possible but the algorithm (I physics, not processing) would also lower sensitivity, also maybe lower contrast. Figure out the math process, then maybe the physics canemulate the algorithm, but make sure it's overall what you'd want.

Comment: The Slashdot post link leads here - https://scitechdaily.com/researchers-develop-sampling-scheme-unconstrained-by-bandwidth/, and then to this original paper - https://www.dropbox.com/s/e7v4m4uhx8255tr/Unlimited%20Sampling.pdf

Comment: @mmesser314 I was actually linking to the comment that described full well depth in an imaging sensor.

Comment: @SeanE.Lake - Yes, sorry. ... leads indirectly ... I thought these links were interesting too.